# How to remove Namespaces when copying nodes to a different node in XML through XSLT1.0?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSL and i'm trying to copy a node of XML to another node in the same XML using XSLT. I can able to transform the file as expected but the XMLNS attribute is getting added to the destination which I don't want.

I have tried all the option of copy-namespaces='no' using XSLT2.0 but that doesn't work. Also, I cant have a prefix of namespaces in the XSLT and use exclude namespaces to avoid xmlns because the incoming XML file is dynamic and namespaces keep on changing. I can't have all the namespaces declared as a prefix in XSLT.

Incoming XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PropertySet>
    <Message>
        <NotificationHeader>
            <BusinessId></BusinessId>
            <CorrelationId>0201201916:21:24CKG3N</CorrelationId>
            <SourceName></SourceName>
            <SourceId></SourceId>
            <EventType></EventType>
            <SecurityIdentifierId></SecurityIdentifierId>
            <ClientRequestId></ClientRequestId>
            <TargetId>ESB</TargetId>
            <EventTime></EventTime>
            <RequestUser></RequestUser>
        </NotificationHeader>
        <EventList>
            <Event>
                <PayLoad>
                    <ListOfActionIo xmlns="http://www.test.com/IO">
                        <Action>
                            <ActivityId>4-309C7WV</ActivityId>
                            <ActivitySRId></ActivitySRId>
                            <ActivityTemplateId></ActivityTemplateId>
                            <ActivityUID>4-309C7WV</ActivityUID>
                            <Category> Notification</Category>
                            <Comment></Comment>
                            <Type>Action</Type>
                            <ListOfDestination>
                                <Destination>
                                    <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
                                </Destination>
                                <Destination>
                                    <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
                                </Destination>
                            </ListOfDestination>
                        </Action>
                    </ListOfActionIo>
                </PayLoad>
            </Event>
        </EventList>
        <DestinationList>
            <Destination>
                <DestinationName></DestinationName>
                <DestinationId></DestinationId>
            </Destination>
        </DestinationList>
    </Message>
</PropertySet>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//*[name()='Message']/*[name()='DestinationList']//*[name()='Destination']"></xsl:template>

    <!--Copy the destination from one node to another node-->

    <xsl:template match="//*[name()='Message']/*[name()='DestinationList']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[name()='Message']/*[name()='EventList']//*[name()='Destination']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Remove the original node from where the destination was copied-->

    <xsl:template match="//*[name()='Message']/*[name()='EventList']//*[name()='ListOfDestination']"></xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    <PropertySet>
   <Message>
      <NotificationHeader>
         <BusinessId/>
         <CorrelationId>0201201916:21:24CKG3N</CorrelationId>
         <SourceName/>
         <SourceId/>
         <EventType/>
         <SecurityIdentifierId/>
         <ClientRequestId/>
         <TargetId>ESB</TargetId>
         <EventTime/>
         <RequestUser/>
      </NotificationHeader>
      <EventList>
         <Event>
            <PayLoad>
               <ListOfActionIo xmlns="http://www.test.com/IO">
                  <Action>
                     <ActivityId>4-309C7WV</ActivityId>
                     <ActivitySRId/>
                     <ActivityTemplateId/>
                     <ActivityUID>4-309C7WV</ActivityUID>
                     <Category> Notification</Category>
                     <Comment/>
                     <Type>Action</Type>
                  </Action>
               </ListOfActionIo>
            </PayLoad>
         </Event>
      </EventList>
      <DestinationList>
         <Destination xmlns="http://www.test.com/IO">
            <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
         </Destination>
         <Destination xmlns="http://www.test.com/IO">
            <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
         </Destination>
      </DestinationList>
   </Message>
</PropertySet>
```

Expected Output:
Without the Namespaces on the copied node.

```
 <PropertySet>
   <Message>
      <NotificationHeader>
         <BusinessId/>
         <CorrelationId>0201201916:21:24CKG3N</CorrelationId>
         <SourceName/>
         <SourceId/>
         <EventType/>
         <SecurityIdentifierId/>
         <ClientRequestId/>
         <TargetId>ESB</TargetId>
         <EventTime/>
         <RequestUser/>
      </NotificationHeader>
      <EventList>
         <Event>
            <PayLoad>
               <ListOfActionIo xmlns="http://www.test.com/IO">
                  <Action>
                     <ActivityId>4-309C7WV</ActivityId>
                     <ActivitySRId/>
                     <ActivityTemplateId/>
                     <ActivityUID>4-309C7WV</ActivityUID>
                     <Category> Notification</Category>
                     <Comment/>
                     <Type>Action</Type>
                  </Action>
               </ListOfActionIo>
            </PayLoad>
         </Event>
      </EventList>
      <DestinationList>
         <Destination>
            <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
         </Destination>
         <Destination>
            <DestinationName>NSW Aboriginal Education Consultative Group Incorporated</DestinationName>
         </Destination>
      </DestinationList>
   </Message>
</PropertySet>
```

Comment: The output you report is not the output one gets using your code.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for trying it out. I have tested the XSLT code with the provided xml input and I get the same output as I have provided. Simulated my code in here http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. You don't want to "remove namespaces" - you want to **change** the namespace of transformed elements. This is akin to renaming the elements.

Now, since your example is confusing (and too long), consider the following:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <colors>
        <color>red</color>
        <color>blue</color>
    </colors>
    <shapes xmlns="some-unknown-namespace">
        <shape>circle</shape>
        <shape>square</shape>
    </shapes>
    <sizes>
        <size>small</size>
        <size>large</size>
    </sizes>
</root>
```

To change the namespace of `shapes` (and its descendants, that inherit it!) to no-namespace, without knowing in advance what the original namespace will be, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::*[name()='shapes']]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <colors>
    <color>red</color>
    <color>blue</color>
  </colors>
  <shapes>
    <shape>circle</shape>
    <shape>square</shape>
  </shapes>
  <sizes>
    <size>small</size>
    <size>large</size>
  </sizes>
</root>
```

---

### Added:

> lets modify the code to move the shapes into sizes and remove the shapes node.

OK, let's do that:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sizes">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!-- move the shapes into sizes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[name()='shapes']/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove the shapes element -->
<xsl:template match="*[name()='shapes']"/>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor::*[name()='shapes']]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <colors>
    <color>red</color>
    <color>blue</color>
  </colors>
  <sizes>
    <size>small</size>
    <size>large</size>
    <shape>circle</shape>
    <shape>square</shape>
  </sizes>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Sorry that my example is too long and confusing. Ok, lets go with your example. Your code is changing the namespace from something to no-namespace as you said. But lets modify the code to move the shapes into sizes and remove the shapes node. You will see the xmlns attribute copied into sizes node. This is what I was asking -> when you move a node into some other node the xmlns attribute of source element is getting added.

Comment: @VinothKumar See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Hi Michael,Perfectly worked. I have modified my code accordingly and I can able to get the desired output. Thanks much!